# How to Texture map a model that has a large number of vertices or faces

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I have a obj model that I imported into blender. The model is a render of a city so its fairly large. As can be seen from the stats in screenshot below (this is after decimating with a ratio of 0.5)
[image]

I also have the texture file for it in png format and I want to map this texture onto the model in blender.

Below is the image I want mapped on the model:

[image]

Ive watched a number of tutorials on how to do this and all direct towards changing the material from base color to texture image and then using UV editing to wrap or unwrap the texture onto the model, but the tutorials show cubes and simple objects and when a face of the model is clicked the region of texture is shown that its taken from. But thats not happening in my case, maybe due to the large number of vertices?

See below the screenshot, on the right the model is zoomed in to show what I mean and nothing is being mapped (other than a solid green color)

[image]

How do I get the texture mapped onto the model?

Thanks

**Update:**

Adding the attempts screenshot based on suggestions in answer:

**UV Mapping**

[image]

**World Coordinates**

[image]

**edit**

Updated model:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem we have two ways. Which one to choose depends on the type of geometry we are working with, as well as the goals.

### **UV Mapping**

Judging by the grid shown in the last screenshot you can just Unwrap the model:

- Select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in Edit Mode
- <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*, (in case of complex geometry you can press <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project from View*
- Use simple texture mappig set in Shader Editor to make texture follow the UV.
  [image]

### **Use World Coordinates**

If the mesh contains so many vertices that blender freezes when you try to unwrap the model - solve this with projecting the texture using Position from Geometry Node as Vector for Image Texture Node. Also you can use mapping node to edit the position of the texture relative to object.
For this solution, you don't need UV.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yuri and yes please I will appreciate he edit as Im very new to blender and dont know where to find the options you just mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer Yuri, but I tried your suggestions and my model and image is not behaving the same way as you have shown in your screenshots. What may the reason be? Ive uploaded the new screenshots to my original question

Comment: Can you attach the file, or if it's too big - append the link to some cloud service, please. Don't forget to include textures, you can do it by File > External Data > Automatically Pack into .blend

Comment: Ive uploaded the models and texture and added the link to question. Thanks a lot for looking into this :)

Comment: I corrected the file according to the instructions I described above. Check it out [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vdOp2f1n3T0I49vQq-eEF5_j7UdSrCch/view?usp=sharing). In order for the map texture to be displayed correctly in world coordinates set you need to configure the mapping node. For Uv mapping > Project from view check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huIQySVEfGk) to clarify the point.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. The video helped with the explanation and I got the material on finally :) In your attached blend file the model looks nicer somehow. Mine looks rough (image attached above), while the one in your project looks nicer.. how can I get this look as well please? Also in my project I cannot rotate the camera otherwise the model disappears, but in your blender project I can freely rotate the camera to view model. Please advise how you fixed that as well. And thank you again for your help Yuri :)

Comment: Update: Right, I figured out that the reason my model would disappear when rotating is because I had to set the clipping value to some very high value. Setting it to 3000m fixed it. I also got the same look as your model, by reducing the z-scale to 0.3. Im happy that I got the same looking model as your project :) but how come the scale in your model is at 1 whereas I had to reduce it to 0.3 to get the same look? Thanks again :)

Comment: @StuckInPhDNoMore Not a problem =). You've got that blinking atrifacts because of small camera cliping for such an huge object. To fix that you can increase cliping amount or just scale down your object to fit in camera clipping. What about scale factor, I just applied it after changing by pressing Ctrl+A > Scale, so it changed back to regular 1. For nicer look you need to go a bit deeper in Shader Editor and how Roughness, Specular and Basic Color works together in Principled BSDF node. To get the same result you can just set Roughness to 1 and Specular to 0.

Comment: Thank you <3 :)